# Nodemon gives UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning upon saving file

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nodemon

I'm using Windows and I've just installed nodemon 2.0.12 (added to path). Whenever I run a basic application it works it should until I save a file, then I receive the following error

[image: nodemon saving error]

My project is a basic express app:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const PORT = 3000

app.use("/", (req, res) => res.send('test'))

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000')
})
```

My `package.json` is as follows

```
{
  "name": "express.1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.j"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading Nodemon to v2.0.7 seems to work. I don't understand why it broke in the first place.